# How to see 'Edit points' on the NURBS curve in Blender? (Equivalent to 'Edit Points' of 'CV Curve Tool' in Maya.)

Tags: nurbs-surface

**Blender:**

[image: Blender]

**Maya:**

[image: Shortcut]

[image: Maya]

How do I make these points visible?

I see the control points and the hulls but not the edit points which normally stay on the line of the NURBS curve. For those who have never used Maya - it basically lets you manipulate the curve directly using those points using the gizmo.

Comment: That sounds more like a Bézier curve. There is an option where one can make a nurbs behave more like a bezier, but I don’t remember where it is exactly in the curve settings or what it does precisely. I might try that out.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard No. CV Curve Tool is used to draw NURBS curve not Bezier curves in Maya. (https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Modeling/files/GUID-2B521AD9-1CB2-43C9-8385-388D118A5AF3-htm.html). Bezier curve has its own tool called 'Bezier Curve Tool'.

Comment: Blender has no edit points on the _NURBS Curve_. And nurbs curves don't necessarily have to have them. To quote the Wikipedia article on NURBS: "Depending on the type of user interface, the editing of NURBS curves and surfaces can be via their control points (similar to Bézier curves) or via higher level tools such as spline modeling and hierarchical editing."

Comment: I don't work with Maya, but reading the articles on the curve tool and edit points on their homepage, the CV Curve Tool actually works like the NURBS Curve in Blender. The Edit Points are not what's shaping the curve and can only make minor adjustments. And of course the Bézier Curve is something else, because a Bézier curve has its control points directly on the curve, while a NURBS curve has them on the hull. [Maya Edit Points](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Maya-Modeling/files/GUID-2B87A277-CED1-4BE5-B242-95CD50184BFF-htm.html)